# Executing multiple Select * in QueryDatabaseTable in NiFi

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, apache-nifi, data-extraction

I want to execute `select * from table1`, `select * from table2`, `select * from table3`,...`select * from table80`....(Basically extract data from 80 different tables and send the data to 80 different indexes in **Elasticsearch(Kibana)**.

Is it possible for me to give multiple `select * statement` in one Query Database Table and then route it to different indexes? If yes, what will be the flow like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple approaches you can take to solve this issue.

- If your tables are literally `table1`, `table2`, etc., you can simply generate 80 flowfiles, each with a unique integer value in an attribute (i.e. `table_count`) and use `GenerateTableFetch` and `ExecuteSQL` to create the queries using this attribute via Expression Language
- If the table names are non-sequential (i.e. `users`, `addresses`, etc.), you can read from a file listing each on a line or use `ListDatabaseTables` to query the database for the names. You can then perform simple text processing to split the created flowfile(s) to one per table and continue as above

Answer (score 1):

**`QueryDatabaseTable`** doesn't allow **incoming connections** so it is `not possible`.

But you can achieve same use case with the following flow

**Flow:**

```
1. ListDatabaseTables
2. RouteOnAttribute //*optional* filter only required tables
3. GenerateTableFetch //to generate pages of sql queries and store state
4. RemoteProcessGroup (or) Load balance connection
5. ExecuteSql //run more than one concurrent task if needed
6. further processing
7. PutElasticSearch.
```

In addition if you don't want to run the flow `incrementally` then remove `GenerateTableFetch` processor

- Configure **`ExecuteSql`** processor select query as

  `select * from ${db.table.schema}.${db.table.name}`

Some useful references:

- GenerateTableFetch [link1](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/61794/how-to-fetch-rows-from-a-table-in-parallel-when-ni.html) [link2](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/147022/what-is-best-way-to-use-querydatabasetable-for-mor.html)
- Incrementally run **`ExecuteSQL`** processor without using `GenerateTableFetch` [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/187764/can-executesql-processor-store-state-for-increment.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply as always. I am still not very clear with the generatetablefetch part. Yes I do want to the incremental fetch. Is there any template available?Or Can u provide a sample Template for the same? Thanks

Comment: What properties to configure in RouteOnAtttribute?

Comment: @shrads, `GenerateTableFetch` processor is used to keep track of state based on max value columns and run generate statements incrementally. `RouteOnAttribute` is used to filter out the required table if you are having `1000's` of tables in DB then the required tables are `80` Configure `${db.table:in("<table1>,...<tablen>")}` (or) you can also configure `ListDatabaseTables` processor to output only required Tables.

Please check my `updated Answer` with **some useful references**..